# Unable to create form tag in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Directory structure.**

[image]

**My current code is below**

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' =>  'SkillsController@store', 'method'  =>  'POST' }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**I got the following error**

> Class 'Form' not found

```
{{!! Form::open(array('action' =>  'SkillsController@store', 'method'  =>  'POST'}}

{{!! Form::close() !!}}
```

**Still I am facing the same issue.**

## **[Reference](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)**

Comment: Do you use the default namespace in your project, or your controller in different namespace?

Comment: Updated the description with Directory Structure.

Comment: Is this the first page you create and contain form in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Laravel 5, Form helpers were removed and are now maintained and provided by the Laravel Collective.

The steps provided in their [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation):

1. Add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` to the require section of your `composer.json` file
2. Run `composer update`
3. Add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` to your array of providers in the `congif/app.php` file
4. Add `'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,` and `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,` to your array of aliases in the `config/app.php` file

You'll then be able to use them in your views using `{!! !!}` in your views, like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: `composer.json` file that is present in `vendor\laravel\framework` ?

Comment: @Helper It is inside your root folder, (i.e inside the same folder as app, bootstrap, config, database, public, resources, storage...)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 HTML, and forms not included you should include manually, can follow instructions in this link.
http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5

Comment: No, you should update your composer file then run the composer to get these files

Comment: Add the following lines in the require section of composer.json file and run composer update "illuminate/html": "5.*"

Comment: You can see if these files exist, then follow all instructions in link